Father of the hero is too shy due to some illness
I can only remember parts of the movie. 

The hero tells his girlfriend that his father is mentally ill whose symptom is being too much shy and not ready to talk to strangers. So the hero requests not to meet with his father, but his girlfriend forces. So he takes her to his house where his father lives a solitary life, seldom speaking to his own son. Possible his wife i.e. the hero's mother was dead. The father is either an archaeologist or he has a hobby of coin collecting because I remember in their first meeting the father was cleaning some coins from some box. The girlfriend tries to communicate with the father. But he talks too small, but it was depicted, given the mental condition the father possesses, the initial amount of talking with the girl was not that bad.
The girlfriend increases meeting with the father and slowly she befriends the father and the father starts talking more with her. Later she requests the father to visit her family so that the father can return the confidence of talking and meeting with strangers. Before going there, all the three persons the hero, girlfriend and his father was having breakfast in the house. In the dining table while eating, the father starts loosing the confidence again. At the end of breakfast, the father almost starts being reluctant to go there. Despite that, the other duo compels him to ride the car and go with them. But in middle of their way, the father stops the car and leaves the car crying and begging pardon to both his son and his girlfriend. Both of them feel sorry again.

This is the part I can only remember. I forgot every other thing about the movie. I believe it is a colour film and not too much old. This is definitely a movie, not animated and made in Hollywood. Except the breakfast thing, I am pretty sure about the other details.
Which movie is this?

I think you are talking about the movie Dear John, starring Channing Tatum as John Tyree who's father is mildly autistic or has Asperger's and for that reason is uncomfortable around people. He has a gigantic coin collection too.

For the time being, I think that's it. AFAIR, the illness was autism which matches with your answer. But can you tell me if the scenes I described are directly from the film for sure?

Ya I am pretty sure. Amanda Seyfried is the actress. She eventually grows close with the father.
